# Can't get jQuery .each() to work

Tags: jquery, html

I have this HTML code in 3 sections of my page:

```
<div class="pjesmarrje">
    <a href="#" onclick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(location.href),'facebook-share-dialog','width=626,height=436'); return false;">
        <div></div>
        <span>Kliko këtu për pjesëmarrje</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

And, I am trying to change the background image of the div inside when its clicked. I got this jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".pjesmarrje").click(function() {
        $(".pjesmarrje div").css("background-image", "url(images/mumanin_s2.png)");
    });
});
```

When I click one of the elements, all the others get their background images changed too. I don't want that to happen, I want the bg image to be changed only when that particular element is clicked. I tried to use the .each() function, but it didn't work.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: $(this).find('div').css("background-image", "url(images/mumanin_s2.png)"); you want to target the div inside the clicked which $(this) refers to the clicked element

Comment: How does this question relate to jQuery .each()?

Comment: If I knew that myself, I wouldn't use StackOverflow. I am a jQuery beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're losing what is referred to as *scope*. If you want it to work within _that specific `.pjesmarrje` you want something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".pjesmarrje").click(function() {
        // `this` is a reference to the `.pjesmarrje` that triggered the click
        // event. and, within that `<div>` we want to find the `<div>` whose
        // background we want to change.
        $("div", this).css("background-image", "url(images/mumanin_s2.png)");
    });
});
```

Note the second argument: `$(selector, scope)`. that means we only care about the `<div>` within the *clicked `.pjesmarrje`* (and not all on the page).

And food for thought: `$('div', this)` is synonymous with `$(this).find('div')`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".pjesmarrje").click(function () {
        $(this).find("div").css("background-image", "url(images/mumanin_s2.png)");
    });
});
```